# Create conditional table row with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I'm an XSLT newbie, so please excuse my ignorance. I need to format football standings from an XML file and create an HTML table. I'm able to do all I need to do except one thing. I need to create a table row above each region, and I can't find a way to do this.

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Result>
  <Standings>
    <Division Name="Region 1A">
      <Team Name="Bogue Chitto" City="Bogue Chitto" State="MS" IsMemberSchool="Yes" League="1A Region 4" Wins="4" Losses="0" Ties="0" WinningPercentage="1.000" PointsFor="185" PointsAgainst="93" LeagueWins="2" LeagueLosses="0" LeagueTies="0" LeagueWinningPercentage="1.000" LeaguePointsFor="95" LeaguePointsAgainst="56" />
      <Team Name="St. Joseph" City="Greenville" State="MS" IsMemberSchool="Yes" League="1A Region 2" Wins="3" Losses="0" Ties="0" WinningPercentage="1.000" PointsFor="126" PointsAgainst="62" LeagueWins="1" LeagueLosses="0" LeagueTies="0" LeagueWinningPercentage="1.000" LeaguePointsFor="37" LeaguePointsAgainst="26" />
      <Team Name="Stringer" City="Stringer" State="MS" IsMemberSchool="Yes" League="1A Region 4" Wins="3" Losses="0" Ties="0" WinningPercentage="1.000" PointsFor="137" PointsAgainst="61" LeagueWins="1" LeagueLosses="0" LeagueTies="0" LeagueWinningPercentage="1.000" LeaguePointsFor="28" LeaguePointsAgainst="14" />
      <Team Name="Durant" City="Durant" State="MS" IsMemberSchool="Yes" League="1A Region 2" Wins="3" Losses="1" Ties="0" WinningPercentage="0.750" PointsFor="77" PointsAgainst="84" LeagueWins="0" LeagueLosses="1" LeagueTies="0" LeagueWinningPercentage="0.000" LeaguePointsFor="6" LeaguePointsAgainst="36" />
      <Team Name="Cathedral" City="Natchez" State="MS" IsMemberSchool="Yes" League="1A Region 4" Wins="3" Losses="1" Ties="0" WinningPercentage="0.750" PointsFor="158" PointsAgainst="142" LeagueWins="1" LeagueLosses="1" LeagueTies="0" LeagueWinningPercentage="0.500" LeaguePointsFor="88" LeaguePointsAgainst="81" />
      <Team Name="Smithville" City="Smithville" State="MS" IsMemberSchool="Yes" League="1A Region 1" Wins="3" Losses="1" Ties="0" WinningPercentage="0.750" PointsFor="99" PointsAgainst="60" LeagueWins="1" LeagueLosses="0" LeagueTies="0" LeagueWinningPercentage="1.000" LeaguePointsFor="22" LeaguePointsAgainst="7" />
      <Team Name="Salem" City="Tylertown" State="MS" IsMemberSchool="Yes" League="1A Region 4" Wins="2" Losses="1" Ties="0" WinningPercentage="0.667" PointsFor="80" PointsAgainst="40" LeagueWins="1" LeagueLosses="1" LeagueTies="0" LeagueWinningPercentage="0.500" LeaguePointsFor="40" LeaguePointsAgainst="40" />
      <Team Name="Sacred Heart" City="Hattiesburg" State="MS" IsMemberSchool="Yes" League="1A Region 4" Wins="2" Losses="1" Ties="0" WinningPercentage="0.667" PointsFor="68" PointsAgainst="54" LeagueWins="0" LeagueLosses="1" LeagueTies="0" LeagueWinningPercentage="0.000" LeaguePointsFor="20" LeaguePointsAgainst="34" />
      <Team Name="Thrasher" City="Booneville" State="MS" IsMemberSchool="Yes" League="1A Region 1" Wins="2" Losses="1" Ties="0" WinningPercentage="0.667" PointsFor="19" PointsAgainst="22" LeagueWins="0" LeagueLosses="1" LeagueTies="0" LeagueWinningPercentage="0.000" LeaguePointsFor="7" LeaguePointsAgainst="22" />
      <Team Name="Broad Street" City="Shelby" State="MS" IsMemberSchool="Yes" League="1A Region 2" Wins="2" Losses="1" Ties="0" WinningPercentage="0.667" PointsFor="62" PointsAgainst="84" LeagueWins="1" LeagueLosses="0" LeagueTies="0" LeagueWinningPercentage="1.000" LeaguePointsFor="22" LeaguePointsAgainst="14" />
      <Team Name="Dexter" City="Tylertown" State="MS" IsMemberSchool="Yes" League="1A Region 4" Wins="2" Losses="1" Ties="0" WinningPercentage="0.667" PointsFor="62" PointsAgainst="74" LeagueWins="1" LeagueLosses="0" LeagueTies="0" LeagueWinningPercentage="1.000" LeaguePointsFor="34" LeaguePointsAgainst="20" />
      <Team Name="Pelahatchie" City="Pelahatchie" State="MS" IsMemberSchool="Yes" League="1A Region 3" Wins="2" Losses="1" Ties="0" WinningPercentage="0.667" PointsFor="124" PointsAgainst="78" LeagueWins="1" LeagueLosses="0" LeagueTies="0" LeagueWinningPercentage="1.000" LeaguePointsFor="47" LeaguePointsAgainst="13" />
      <Team Name="Hamilton" City="Hamilton" State="MS" IsMemberSchool="Yes" League="1A Region 1" Wins="3" Losses="2" Ties="0" WinningPercentage="0.600" PointsFor="117" PointsAgainst="92" LeagueWins="1" LeagueLosses="1" LeagueTies="0" LeagueWinningPercentage="0.500" LeaguePointsFor="58" LeaguePointsAgainst="39" />
      <Team Name="Falkner" City="Falkner" State="MS" IsMemberSchool="Yes" League="1A Region 1" Wins="2" Losses="2" Ties="0" WinningPercentage="0.500" PointsFor="137" PointsAgainst="148" LeagueWins="1" LeagueLosses="0" LeagueTies="0" LeagueWinningPercentage="1.000" LeaguePointsFor="32" LeaguePointsAgainst="27" />
      <Team Name="Noxapater" City="Noxapater" State="MS" IsMemberSchool="Yes" League="1A Region 3" Wins="2" Losses="2" Ties="0" WinningPercentage="0.500" PointsFor="89" PointsAgainst="73" LeagueWins="1" LeagueLosses="0" LeagueTies="0" LeagueWinningPercentage="1.000" LeaguePointsFor="20" LeaguePointsAgainst="13" />
      <Team Name="Nanih Waiya" City="Louisville" State="MS" IsMemberSchool="Yes" League="1A Region 3" Wins="2" Losses="2" Ties="0" WinningPercentage="0.500" PointsFor="113" PointsAgainst="88" LeagueWins="1" LeagueLosses="0" LeagueTies="0" LeagueWinningPercentage="1.000" LeaguePointsFor="47" LeaguePointsAgainst="13" />
      <Team Name="Shaw" City="Shaw" State="MS" IsMemberSchool="Yes" League="1A Region 2" Wins="2" Losses="2" Ties="0" WinningPercentage="0.500" PointsFor="77" PointsAgainst="64" LeagueWins="1" LeagueLosses="0" LeagueTies="0" LeagueWinningPercentage="1.000" LeaguePointsFor="36" LeaguePointsAgainst="6" />
      <Team Name="Sebastopol" City="Sebastopol" State="MS" IsMemberSchool="Yes" League="1A Region 3" Wins="2" Losses="2" Ties="0" WinningPercentage="0.500" PointsFor="128" PointsAgainst="112" LeagueWins="1" LeagueLosses="0" LeagueTies="0" LeagueWinningPercentage="1.000" LeaguePointsFor="47" LeaguePointsAgainst="0" />
      <Team Name="St. Aloysius" City="Vicksburg" State="MS" IsMemberSchool="Yes" League="1A Region 2" Wins="2" Losses="2" Ties="0" WinningPercentage="0.500" PointsFor="88" PointsAgainst="65" LeagueWins="1" LeagueLosses="0" LeagueTies="0" LeagueWinningPercentage="1.000" LeaguePointsFor="48" LeaguePointsAgainst="20" />
      <Team Name="Resurrection Catholic" City="Pascagoula" State="MS" IsMemberSchool="Yes" League="1A Region 4" Wins="2" Losses="2" Ties="0" WinningPercentage="0.500" PointsFor="123" PointsAgainst="66" LeagueWins="0" LeagueLosses="2" LeagueTies="0" LeagueWinningPercentage="0.000" LeaguePointsFor="46" LeaguePointsAgainst="66" />
    </Division>
    <Division Name="Region 2A">
      <Team Name="Byers" City="Holly Springs" State="MS" IsMemberSchool="Yes" League="2A Region 2" Wins="4" Losses="0" Ties="0" WinningPercentage="1.000" PointsFor="144" PointsAgainst="58" LeagueWins="0" LeagueLosses="0" LeagueTies="0" LeagueWinningPercentage="0.000" LeaguePointsFor="0" LeaguePointsAgainst="0" />
      <Team Name="Bassfield" City="Bassfield" State="MS" IsMemberSchool="Yes" League="2A Region 7" Wins="4" Losses="0" Ties="0" WinningPercentage="1.000" PointsFor="154" PointsAgainst="47" LeagueWins="0" LeagueLosses="0" LeagueTies="0" LeagueWinningPercentage="0.000" LeaguePointsFor="0" LeaguePointsAgainst="0" />
      <Team Name="East Webster" City="Maben" State="MS" IsMemberSchool="Yes" League="2A Region 4" Wins="4" Losses="0" Ties="0" WinningPercentage="1.000" PointsFor="129" PointsAgainst="65" LeagueWins="0" LeagueLosses="0" LeagueTies="0" LeagueWinningPercentage="0.000" LeaguePointsFor="0" LeaguePointsAgainst="0" />
      <Team Name="Richton" City="Richton" State="MS" IsMemberSchool="Yes" League="2A Region 8" Wins="4" Losses="0" Ties="0" WinningPercentage="1.000" PointsFor="129" PointsAgainst="53" LeagueWins="0" LeagueLosses="0" LeagueTies="0" LeagueWinningPercentage="0.000" LeaguePointsFor="0" LeaguePointsAgainst="0" />
      <Team Name="Lake" City="Lake" State="MS" IsMemberSchool="Yes" League="2A Region 5" Wins="4" Losses="0" Ties="0" WinningPercentage="1.000" PointsFor="184" PointsAgainst="42" LeagueWins="0" LeagueLosses="0" LeagueTies="0" LeagueWinningPercentage="0.000" LeaguePointsFor="0" LeaguePointsAgainst="0" />
      <Team Name="Eupora" City="Eupora" State="MS" IsMemberSchool="Yes" League="2A Region 4" Wins="4" Losses="0" Ties="0" WinningPercentage="1.000" PointsFor="176" PointsAgainst="49" LeagueWins="0" LeagueLosses="0" LeagueTies="0" LeagueWinningPercentage="0.000" LeaguePointsFor="0" LeaguePointsAgainst="0" />
      <Team Name="East Union" City="Blue Springs" State="MS" IsMemberSchool="Yes" League="2A Region 1" Wins="4" Losses="0" Ties="0" WinningPercentage="1.000" PointsFor="118" PointsAgainst="56" LeagueWins="0" LeagueLosses="0" LeagueTies="0" LeagueWinningPercentage="0.000" LeaguePointsFor="0" LeaguePointsAgainst="0" />
      <Team Name="Bruce" City="Bruce" State="MS" IsMemberSchool="Yes" League="2A Region 4" Wins="3" Losses="1" Ties="0" WinningPercentage="0.750" PointsFor="100" PointsAgainst="63" LeagueWins="0" LeagueLosses="0" LeagueTies="0" LeagueWinningPercentage="0.000" LeaguePointsFor="0" LeaguePointsAgainst="0" />
      <Team Name="Walnut" City="Walnut" State="MS" IsMemberSchool="Yes" League="2A Region 1" Wins="3" Losses="1" Ties="0" WinningPercentage="0.750" PointsFor="128" PointsAgainst="102" LeagueWins="0" LeagueLosses="0" LeagueTies="0" LeagueWinningPercentage="0.000" LeaguePointsFor="0" LeaguePointsAgainst="0" />
      <Team Name="Leland" City="Leland" State="MS" IsMemberSchool="Yes" League="2A Region 3" Wins="3" Losses="1" Ties="0" WinningPercentage="0.750" PointsFor="93" PointsAgainst="68" LeagueWins="0" LeagueLosses="0" LeagueTies="0" LeagueWinningPercentage="0.000" LeaguePointsFor="0" LeaguePointsAgainst="0" />
      <Team Name="Mize" City="Mize" State="MS" IsMemberSchool="Yes" League="2A Region 8" Wins="3" Losses="1" Ties="0" WinningPercentage="0.750" PointsFor="125" PointsAgainst="96" LeagueWins="0" LeagueLosses="0" LeagueTies="0" LeagueWinningPercentage="0.000" LeaguePointsFor="0" LeaguePointsAgainst="0" />
      <Team Name="Taylorsville" City="Taylorsville" State="MS" IsMemberSchool="Yes" League="2A Region 8" Wins="3" Losses="1" Ties="0" WinningPercentage="0.750" PointsFor="101" PointsAgainst="35" LeagueWins="0" LeagueLosses="0" LeagueTies="0" LeagueWinningPercentage="0.000" LeaguePointsFor="0" LeaguePointsAgainst="0" />
      <Team Name="Mantachie" City="Mantachie" State="MS" IsMemberSchool="Yes" League="2A Region 1" Wins="3" Losses="1" Ties="0" WinningPercentage="0.750" PointsFor="158" PointsAgainst="110" LeagueWins="0" LeagueLosses="0" LeagueTies="0" LeagueWinningPercentage="0.000" LeaguePointsFor="0" LeaguePointsAgainst="0" />
      <Team Name="East Marion" City="Columbia" State="MS" IsMemberSchool="Yes" League="2A Region 7" Wins="3" Losses="1" Ties="0" WinningPercentage="0.750" PointsFor="75" PointsAgainst="60" LeagueWins="0" LeagueLosses="0" LeagueTies="0" LeagueWinningPercentage="0.000" LeaguePointsFor="0" LeaguePointsAgainst="0" />
      <Team Name="Calhoun City" City="Calhoun City" State="MS" IsMemberSchool="Yes" League="2A Region 4" Wins="3" Losses="1" Ties="0" WinningPercentage="0.750" PointsFor="109" PointsAgainst="71" LeagueWins="0" LeagueLosses="0" LeagueTies="0" LeagueWinningPercentage="0.000" LeaguePointsFor="0" LeaguePointsAgainst="0" />
    </Division>
    </Standings>
</Result>
```

And this is my current XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="Result">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>Standings</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#C0C0C0">
        <th>Team</th>
        <th>Region</th>
        <th>Div. W</th>
        <th>Div. L</th>
         <th>Div. T</th>
          <th>Div. Pct.</th>
        <th>Wins</th>
        <th>Losses</th>
        <th>Ties</th>
        <th>Pct.</th>
        <th>PF</th>
        <th>PA</th>
</tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="Standings/Division">
      <tr align="center">    
<td colspan="12" bgcolor="#D3D3D3">Class <xsl:value-of select='substring(@Name,7,3)'/></td>
</tr>
<tr align="center"><td colspan="12" bgcolor="#D3D3D3">Region 1</td></tr>
<xsl:for-each select="./Team">
   <xsl:sort select="@League"/> 
   <xsl:sort select="@LeagueWinningPercentage" order="descending"/>
    <xsl:sort select="@LeagueWins" order="descending"/>
     <xsl:sort select="@WinningPercentage" order="descending"/>
     <xsl:sort select="@Wins" order="descending"/>
     <xsl:sort select="@Name" order="ascending"/> 
      <tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="@Name"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select='substring(@League,4,9)'/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="@LeagueWins"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="@LeagueLosses"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="@LeagueTies"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="@LeagueWinningPercentage"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="@Wins"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="@Losses"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="@Ties"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="@WinningPercentage"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="@PointsFor"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="@PointsAgainst"/></td>
 </tr>
       </xsl:for-each>   
</xsl:for-each>
     </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The final output should look like this:

[Formatted results should look like this:](http://www.misshsaa.com/GeneralInfo/NewsAnnouncements/tabid/97/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/1394/Football-standings-for-week-of-9-30.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works well and only requires a minor modification to get the region headings working:

Replace the hard-coded "Region 1" string in your XSLT with this statement:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
```

This will create "Region 1", "Region 2", etc in the rows you've already formated properly for the region information.  Your code is actually already pulling from `Description/@Name` for the Region column of your table.  Is there something different or more that you need to change?